# Facebook Client Token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new faceboookSDK for Android.
I want to fetch the feed of a fanpage from facebook over the facebook Graph API. I know that it is possible, if the user is logged in.

Now my question:

Is there any solution to fetch the public facebook feed of a fanpage without loggin in?
What is the client token and what it is used for? It seems that there is no documentation about the client token usage.

I can't find any example or description in the documentation.

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens has a short explanation what a _client token_ is. But it doesn’t sound like you can use it for such API calls.

Comment: Why to find the client token? The doc says to look in app dashborad but i only see appid and secret key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without login, you can use an App Access Token. It is valid forever, but you can´t get access to restricted Pages. If a Page is restricted by age or location, you have to use a User Token - else it would be impossible to detect if the User is allowed to see the Page or its content.

More information about Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

You can also check out the API reference to find out which tokens you can use: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#read

Btw, App Tokens should never be used in client-side code, as they include the App Secret (which is called "secret" for a reason). Same for Extended Page Tokens, because they are valid forever as well. You should cache results on your own server anyway, and access your server/database with the Android App instead of hitting the Graph API directly all the time.

Comment: Don’t forget to mention that both app and page tokens do not belong into client-side code (OP is asking about an Android app here), but that calls using those tokens only should be made server-side.

Comment: Thanks for your replys. So I have to make a request to my server. And on my server the app access token is stored to make the requests to the facebook servers. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. You don’t need to “request” an app access token though (as the documentation suggests) – the combination of app id and app secret with a pipe symbol in the middle (`appid|appsecret`)  always works as an app access token.